# How to get probabilities from Resnet using pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am finetuning resnet on my dataset which has multiple labels.

I would like to convert the 'scores' of the classification  layer to probabilities and use those probabilities to calculate the loss at the training.

Could you give an example code for this?
Can I use like this:

```
       P = net.forward(x)
       p = torch.nn.functional.softmax(P, dim=1)
       loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(P, y)
```

I am unclear whether this is the correct way or not as I am passing probabilities as the input to crossentropy loss.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, you are training a `model` i.e resnet with cross-entropy in pytorch. Your loss calculation would look like this.

```
logit = model(x)
loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(logits=logit, target=y)
```

In this case, you can calculate the probabilities of all classes by doing,

```
logit = model(x)
p = torch.nn.functional.softmax(logit, dim=1)
# to calculate loss using probabilities you can do below 
loss = torch.nn.functional.nll_loss(torch.log(p), y)
```

Note that if you use probabilities you will have to manually take a `log`, which is bad for numerical reasons. Instead, either use `log_softmax` or `cross_entropy` in which case you may end up computing losses using cross entropy and computing probability separately.

Comment: I would like to convert my 'scores' to probabilities and use those probabilities to calculate the loss at the training.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question. Please have a look.